# How do I speed up a Python nested loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the gravity effect of a buried object by calculating the effect on each side of the body and then summing up the contributions to get one measurement at one station, and repeating for a number of stations. The code is as follows (the body is a square and the code calculates clockwise around it. That's why it goes from -x back to -x coordinates).

```
grav = []
x = si.arange(-30.0, 30.0, 0.5)

# -9.79742526     9.78716693    22.32153704    27.07382349  2138.27146193
xcorn = (-9.79742526,  9.78716693,  9.78716693, -9.79742526, -9.79742526)
zcorn = (22.32153704, 22.32153704, 27.07382349, 27.07382349, 22.32153704)
gamma = (6.672*(10**-11)) # 'N m^2 / Kg^2'
rho = 2138.27146193 # 'Kg / m^3'
grav = []
iter_time = []
def procedure():
    for i in si.arange(len(x)): # Cycles position
        t0 = time.clock()
        sum_lines = 0.0

        for n in si.arange(len(xcorn)-1): # Cycles corners
            x1 = xcorn[n]   - x[i]
            x2 = xcorn[n+1] - x[i]
            z1 = zcorn[n]   -0.0  # Just depth to corner since all observations are on the surface.
            z2 = zcorn[n+1] -0.0
            r1 = ((z1**2) + (x1**2))**0.5
            r2 = ((z2**2) + (x2**2))**0.5
            O1 = si.arctan2(z1, x1)
            O2 = si.arctan2(z2, x2)
            denom = z2-z1
            if denom == 0.0:
                denom = 1.0e-6

            alpha = (x2-x1)/denom

            beta = ((x1*z2)-(x2*z1))/denom
            factor = (beta/(1.0 + (alpha**2)))
            term1 = si.log(r2/r1) # Log base 10
            term2 = alpha*(O2-O1)
            sum_lines = sum_lines + (factor*(term1-term2))
        sum_lines = sum_lines*2*gamma*rho
        grav.append(sum_lines)
        t1 = time.clock()
        dt = t1-t0
        iter_time.append(dt)
```

How can I speed this loop up?

Comment: Suggesting http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  A better forum for this type questions.

Comment: @aix: `si.arange()` might suggest that he uses `numpy` arrays already.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Good catch. I've removed my comment to not cause any further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your xcorn and zcorn values repeat, so consider caching the result of some of the computations.

Take a look at the timeit and profile modules to get more information about what is taking the most computational time.

Answer (score 1):

It is very inefficient to access individual elements of a NumPy array in a Python loop. For example, this Python loop:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(a), 2):
    a[i] = i
```

would be much slower than:

```
a[::2] = np.arange(0, len(a), 2)
```

You could use a better algorithm (less time complexity) or use vector operations on NumPy arrays as in the example above. But the quicker way might be just to compile the code using [Cython](http://cython.org):

```
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False
#procedure_module.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t

def procedure(np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=1] x,
              np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=1] xcorn):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j
        dtype_t x1, x2, z1, z2, r1, r2, O1, O2
        np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=1] grav = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(xcorn.shape[0]-1):
            x1 = xcorn[j]-x[i]
            x2 = xcorn[j+1]-x[i]
            ...
        grav[i] = ...
    return grav
```

It is not necessary to define all types, but if you need a significant speedup compared to Python, you should define at least types of arrays and loop indexes.

You could use [`cProfile`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/profile) (Cython supports it) instead of manual calls to `time.clock()`.

To call `procedure()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyximport; pyximport.install() # pip install cython
import numpy as np

from procedure_module import procedure

x = np.arange(-30.0, 30.0, 0.5)
xcorn = np.array((-9.79742526, 9.78716693, 9.78716693, -9.79742526, -9.79742526))
grav = procedure(x, xcorn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, il take a look at cython and see if that helps, im not worried about the time.clock() because ive only got that in there to see how fast each iteration is taking while i try and speed it up, its not a necessary part of the code.